# i want to design one small software for 1st standard student for educational purpose

Tags: software-recommendation

i want to design one small software for 1st standard student for educational purpose. will you sugest some best software /game making tool, which i can understand fast also write small applications very fast. I have complete engineering in electronics, hence having very little knowledge of programming.

Comment: Are you ready to learn a simple and powerful language called python?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Python.  It is a lovely language and has some excellent gui and games libraries.  It can also run on any platform.